# http error 502 when accessing paypal.com through proxy

Tags: paypal, https, proxy

Sigh. The header says it all, really. I'm trying to go to paypal.com through a proxy of mine. And the result is a 502 error. There's a long waiting time before that happens. And it's the same on some other secure sites. Yes, of course, paypal uses https. So does stackoverflow, but I have no trouble going to SO through my proxy. What's going on here? I suspect paypal uses a firewall and tries to detect bots accessing from web servers. But is it somehow against the rules to access through a proxy? How does paypal see the difference between a person surfing from a browser and a script running on a server? I mean I can't even get at the home page; this has nothing to do with logging in.

I haven't investigated much so far because I'm hoping that some hacker out there already knows all about this and can guide me along. I'm only speculating. Are the request headers sent to paypal somehow incompatible? I impersonate a user agent that possibly contradicts some header that the server adds without my knowledge? Does paypal check the ip address and decide that it's a web server? Can you see that even from the headers? The proxy uses https - it doesn't tunnel. Does that lead to paypal seeing the certificate of the web server?

I'm sure paypal has lots of protective software sniffing at the requests coming in. To prevent DDOS attacks? To defeat hackers? To exclude bots? A proxy is not exactly a bot, it just relays requests from a human user. Anyway, what's the difference, as seen by paypal, between a request from a browser and from a proxy?

Comment: I use paypal via proxy all the time, what proxy are you using, and is it doing https inspection?

Comment: It's one of my own making. There were several issues with it, none specific to paypal. I solved it, now it works. Paypal is a demanding professional website and exposed the shortcomings of my proxy.